# Using CURL in function in c++

Tags: c++, function, curl, libcurl

I'm trying tu use curl in c++ using function.
Example:

```html
#define ...
...
...

/*  CURL parameters */
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
CURLcode res;
string readBuffer;

void setHeader(){
    if(curl) {
        /*  Headers */
        struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
        chunk = NULL;
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Connection:keep-alive");
        ..
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer); 
    }    
}

void myFunction1(){
    setHeader();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "....");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, cookiePath);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, cookiePath);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    cout << readBuffer;
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
}

void myFunction2(){
    setHeader();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "....");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, cookiePath);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, cookiePath);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    cout << readBuffer;
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

In the main function i call myFunction1 or myFunction2;

I don't know if is right to use libcurl in this way, but I'm having a problem.
I use this to login in my site, so I save the cookie whit this code:

```html
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, cookiePath);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, cookiePath);
```

```html
int main(){
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
myFunction1();
myFunction2();
curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

Suppose i login and save the cookie in myFunction1.
When I'm trying to set in the myFunction2 it crash on the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE row.
I don't know why the cookie is saved in the file, but it can't be used beacuse when I run the program it crash on that row.

Sorry for my English
Thank's

Comment: Can you post your `main()` function where `curl_global_init` is called?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.html) option reference?

Comment: I've not used curl_global_init, is it necessary?

Comment: Try calling `curl_global_init()` at the beginning of `main()` and `curl_global_cleanup()` at the end.

Comment: You should call `curl_global_init` at least once. See [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html). If it is not called explicitly, it is called implicitly from `curl_easy_init` but is not threadsafe and is virtually fatal if called from multiple threads.

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded?

Comment: where and how is `cookiePath` declared and assigned before passed to curl?  Also, both functions are calling `curl_easy_cleanup()`.  If both functions are actually called, you will have issues, since `curl_easy_cleanup()` destroys the `CURL` object created by `curl_easy_init()`, per the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_cleanup.html): "*Any use of the **handle** after this function has been called and have returned, is illegal. curl_easy_cleanup kills the handle and all memory associated with it!*"

Comment: 1) My program is not multithread, 
2)I have added curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);  and curl_global_cleanup(); in the main where I call the myfunction1 and the myfunction2. 
3)I've editet the post adding the main code

The program crash on the row of the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, but I can't understand why.

Comment: Either call curl_easy_init, curl_easy_cleanup and all common curl_easy_setopt in main; or call **all** of those in **both** myfunction1 and myfunction2 (which will then use different CURL objects).

Comment: You're right.
I've solved in that way:
in each function use curl = curl_easy init; and curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

Thank's to all

Answer (score 0):

The reason of my problem is that when I use the curl_easy_cleanup(curl) and then curl_easy_init I change the sessionID, so the cookie that I've saved are no longer good. So I use at the first curl_easy_init, then I make all my request in my functions, and at the end of my program I use curl_easy_cleanup. To clean the CURL OPTION you can use: curl_easy_reset(). I've update this post for people that can have my same problem.